# Convert Laravel collection to Array without out quotes before and after brackets

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

How to i remove the quotes before array opening bracket and after closing bracket.

```
private function get_sector_id ()
{
    $sectors = SectorUser::select('sector_id')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->pluck('sector_id');

    dd(json_encode($sectors));
}
```

Output before json_encode:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#310 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => "49ea267e-d11d-4fe9-ba62-c16d620688a3"
    1 => "6ba71f44-3c29-4fe3-b7ce-9d8a15e60f33"
  ]
}
```

tried to use json_encode but returns with quotes before and after array brackets

```
"["49ea267e-d11d-4fe9-ba62-c16d620688a3","6ba71f44-3c29-4fe3-b7ce-9d8a15e60f33"]"
```

i want to convert the output to brackets array so i can use in query whereNotIn,

target is:

```
["49ea267e-d11d-4fe9-ba62-c16d620688a3","6ba71f44-3c29-4fe3-b7ce-9d8a15e60f33"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following code returns a Collection with elements being sector_ids.

```
$sectors = SectorUser::select('sector_id')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->pluck('sector_id');
```

Luckily Laravels whereNotIn can take Collections or Arrays. Simply doing the following will work. As can be seen [here](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/31e65770a0c4daaf59f16b23217d206be6da4e4b/Query/Builder.php#L910).

```
$sectorsWithoutSome = Sectors::whereNotIn($sectors)->get();
```

I would argue, for other than responses, it is an anti pattern to convert your internal models to JSON with json_encode. There is often way better approaches.

Comment: Bonus info, the string info is because you are returning a string. Laravel can automatically encode it if you return it in the API.

Comment: this works super! and thank you for the advice on how to convert JSON, and i'll read more about it

Answer (score 0):

Use flatten on your collection.

`$sectors->flatten();`

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-flatten